# Authorization tokens with many sessions

Tags: authentication

at this time i have a question related to how to do a multi auth token sessions; because it has a limitation when the user login into the system and try to do the same in other machine, the tokens are changed(A token by user), we would like has a multiple tokens sessions, that means that we need store all tokens in order to have many connections, but it's not clear how we need to store that and destroy the sessions: we have a solution that follow like this:

**[User] =>(has many) => [tokens]**, when user sign in a new token is created and so on. at the end of the day we have many tokens with the same user. that's is not a best practice.

there is another best approach form to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

In this case the solution was implement a table called authorizations and save there all keys in order to find and asociate to a user, then i need to expire in any period of time. use redis or delayed_job to remove it.